# Finding it difficult to white out a section and present a button

Tags: css

I have a bunch of elements inside my features section -- I want this section to turn white and present a button saying "next question" when the timer reaches zero. I've already got the javascript complete (so when the timer reaches zero, some function will be called to change css styles) and it works fine.

Problem is, I can't figure out what to modify or do in terms of css to actually achieve my desired effect. The thing I'm having trouble with is whiting out the section except for the "next question" button. This is what it looks like right now:
 [image]

I want to turn that entire section white over the text, timers, and start and skip buttons.

html:

```
<section class="features">

        <p class = 'new-question'> The text displaying MMI questions will go here. </p>

        <div class = 'middle-center'>
        <h2>Completed</h2>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-next-question'>Next Question</button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'bottom-right'>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-start'>Start</button>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-skip'>Skip</button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'bottom-left timer-style'>
        <span id ='countdown-2-minutes'>2:00</span>
        <span id ='countdown-8-minutes'>8:00</span>    
        </div>


</section>
```

css:

```
.features {
position: relative;
margin-top: 10px;
min-height: 400px;
border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #BA8960;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.new-question {
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

/* buttons */
.timer-style{
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 15px 10px;
span{
margin: 0px 20px;

}

.bottom-right{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;

}
.bottom-left{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}

.middle-center{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 2 suggestions, where I added this CSS rule to the first sample (using opacity)

```
.features.white-it > *:not(.middle-center) {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

and this to the second sample (using pseudo)

```
.features.white-it:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
}
.features.white-it > *:not(.middle-center) {
  z-index: 1;
}
.features.white-it .middle-center {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Now, with your script, simply add the class `white-it` to the `.feature` div.

Sample 1

```css
.features {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #BA8960;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.new-question {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

/* buttons */
.timer-style{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}
span{
  margin: 0px 20px;

}
.bottom-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;

}
.bottom-left{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.middle-center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.features.white-it > *:not(.middle-center) {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<section class="features white-it">

        <p class = 'new-question'> The text displaying MMI questions will go here. </p>

        <div class = 'middle-center'>
        <h2>Completed</h2>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-next-question'>Next Question</button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'bottom-right'>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-start'>Start</button>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-skip'>Skip</button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'bottom-left timer-style'>
        <span id ='countdown-2-minutes'>2:00</span>
        <span id ='countdown-8-minutes'>8:00</span>    
        </div>


</section>
```

Sample 2

```css
.features {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #BA8960;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.new-question {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

/* buttons */
.timer-style{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}
span{
  margin: 0px 20px;

}
.bottom-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;

}
.bottom-left{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.middle-center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.features.white-it:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
}
.features.white-it > *:not(.middle-center) {
  z-index: 1;
}
.features.white-it .middle-center {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="features white-it">

        <p class = 'new-question'> The text displaying MMI questions will go here. </p>

        <div class = 'middle-center'>
        <h2>Completed</h2>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-next-question'>Next Question</button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'bottom-right'>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-start'>Start</button>
        <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-skip'>Skip</button>
        </div>

        <div class = 'bottom-left timer-style'>
        <span id ='countdown-2-minutes'>2:00</span>
        <span id ='countdown-8-minutes'>8:00</span>    
        </div>


</section>
```

Comment: thank you -- this  worked great (plus I learned some new css!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mask"></div>    
<section class="features">

    <p class = 'new-question'> The text displaying MMI questions will go here. </p>

    <div class = 'middle-center'>
    <h2>Completed</h2>
    <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-next-question'>Next Question</button>
    </div>

    <div class = 'bottom-right'>
    <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-start'>Start</button>
    <button type='button' class='nbtn nbtn-1 nbtn-1a btn-skip'>Skip</button>
    </div>

    <div class = 'bottom-left timer-style'>
    <span id ='countdown-2-minutes'>2:00</span>
    <span id ='countdown-8-minutes'>8:00</span>    
    </div>
</section>

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.middle center {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

You need the rest of your css (there's a missing bracket in it) as well as this. Hide and display the .mask on your timer.

https://jsfiddle.net/ne9xeppf/